# syntax error with COPY INTO snowflake command

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to populate a table already created in Snowflake from a file in an s3 bucket. I have verified that the Storage Integration is working and so according to the docs, I don't need an External Stage.

It also seems that in order to populate a table using a Parquet file format, I need to specify the columns in the copy command, per posts [in Snowflake community forum.](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000077913sSAA/how-to-copy-parquet-file-into-table)

My command is giving a syntax error no matter what changes I make. If I remove the '(' after the s3 bucket url, I get the error

```
    "unexpected SELECT"
```

but if I leave it in, I get the error

```
    "unexpected '(' "
```

My code:

```
    COPY INTO MYTABLE
        FROM s3://bucket/folder2/File.snappy.parquet (
       SELECT 
       O_ID: NUMBER(19,0),        

       O_TYPE:VARCHAR(48),        

       C_ID:NUMBER(19,0),

       ON_ID:FLOAT,

       SE_ID:NUMBER(19,0),

       C_MATCH:BOOLEAN 

    )

        STORAGE_INTEGRATION = MY_INTEGRATION
        FILE_FORMAT=(
           TYPE = 'PARQUET' 
          SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE
       )
      ;
```

Can someone tell me how to fix the syntax here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your command should be like

```
COPY INTO MYTABLE ( 
   O_ID: NUMBER(19,0),        
   O_TYPE:VARCHAR(48),        
   C_ID:NUMBER(19,0),
   ON_ID:FLOAT,
   SE_ID:NUMBER(19,0),
   C_MATCH:BOOLEAN 
   )
   FROM ( 
    SELECT $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 FROM s3://bucket/folder2/File.snappy.parquet 
   ) STORAGE_INTEGRATION = MY_INTEGRATION
    FILE_FORMAT=(
       TYPE = 'PARQUET' 
      SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE
   );
```

Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: I get  syntax error line 2 at position 21 unexpected ':' with this. what to use instead of the ':'?

Comment: update: I removed all the datatype values and also due to another error message, changed the url to s3n. Now, I get the error "SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import." I thought the Storage Integration made the stage unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Table needs to be created before COPY INTO:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MYTABLE (
    O_ID NUMBER(19,0),        
    O_TYPE VARCHAR(48),        
    C_ID NUMBER(19,0),
    ON_ID FLOAT,
    SE_ID NUMBER(19,0),
    C_MATCH BOOLEAN 
);


COPY INTO MYTABLE (
    O_ID,        
    O_TYPE,     
    C_ID,
    ON_ID,
    SE_ID
)
FROM s3://bucket/folder2/File.snappy.parquet

STORAGE_INTEGRATION = MY_INTEGRATION
FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE = 'PARQUET' 
    SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE
)
;
```

Comment: Thanks - I edited my post to indicate that the table had already been created. The issue I'm facing now is that I get 'COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import' when running my modified command.

Comment: You modified query still not valid, you should not have column types in the SELECT statement. Can you try to remove the column types?